# CyclicBarrier: Of 'x' threads that cause the barrier to trip 'y' complete their execution and terminate

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, barrier, cyclicbarrier

I have a CyclicBarrier that will trip when 'x' number of parties (threads) are waiting upon it. Among these 'x' threads 'y' have very small life spans and terminate much quickly after completing their execution successfully. Now, the barrier keeps waiting and times out since it keeps waiting on 'x' threads. How can I solve this issue?

```
CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(NUM_THREADS, new UpdateState());

private class UpdateState implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
            if (availability[i]) {
                // Update condition for "i'th" thread to run
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public long write() throws IOException {
   waitForTurn();
}

private void waitForTurn() {
   while (!canSchedule()) {
       try {
          barrier.await();
       }  catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // Assert fail
       }  catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
          // Assert fail
       }
   }
}

private boolean canSchedule() {
   return // some state checks;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
     Future<Long> responseFuture = executorService.submit(new Task(...));
     responses.add(responseFuture);
   }

   executorService.shutdown();
   executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   // Check futures
}
```

Now say task1, invokes write() 5 times and task2 invokes write 500 times..then task1 will terminate after hitting the barrier 5 times but task2 will continue to run.

Comment: What do you mean, "trip"? Also, can you show the relevant code?

Comment: How do the `y` threads terminate successfully without the barrier being triggered?

Comment: barrier is triggered, please see the sample code.

Answer (score 2):

To really use the CyclicBarrier ALL threads must `await` on the barrier to trip it successfuly.  Your statement confuses me

> Among these 'x' threads 'y' have very small life spans and terminate
>   much quickly after completing their execution successfully.

If the 'y' threads/tasks complete very quickly, why are they not waiting on the barrier?  If you have all 'y' threads waiting on the barrier when they complete, then the rest of the threads (x-y) will soon await and trip the barrier.